# How to properly use sequences for attribution?

Tags: google-analytics

My goal is to see which customers originate from organic search, but convert via a different source later on.

To do this, I defined this segment:

[image]

Then, I look at the Source/Medium report, but the results seem off. I expected to see zero revenue in the google/organic row (as the segment should show users where the transaction is specifically *not* coming from google/organic.

[image]

Am I using the right tool for what I'm trying to achieve? And if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the solution is to add a condition that includes only sessions as described in the second step of the sequence. This will reduce the population from all users that present the pattern in the sequence, to only sessions that matter. At least adding that condition works as I expected the original solution to work.

Comment: While I think this is an excellent question it is not really in the scope of this site as defined by the help center https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: You're right @EikePierstorff. Duly noted. I'll answer the question and leave just in case anyone encounters in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a condition that includes only sessions as described in the second step of the sequence. This will reduce the population from all users that present the pattern in the sequence, to only sessions that matter. See detailed explanation here: https://www.napkyn.com/2017/09/07/quick-google-analytics-trick-use-sequence-segments-to-analyse-behavior-over-multiple-sessions/

Answer (score 0):

The conversion path in Google Analytics is a better solution here. You can find it under **conversions -> multi-channel funnels -> top conversion paths**.

What you're going to see here is all the combinations of channels that have been used to generate a conversion, see the screenshot below.

[image]

If you have a bigger website you're probably going to have >10.000 different conversion paths depending on the time period that you select. What you want to realize is how much conversion value and conversion was generated in conversion paths that *started with organic, but ended with a different channel*. Simply apply the filter below in the report to retrieve that data. Please note that in the standard Google Analytics reports all conversions and conversion value are attributed to the last, non-direct click. [image]

Comment: This will work, yes, but its not the solution i was looking for. I wanted to do this using sequences :)